# No me aparecen los simuladores de xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone

[image: no simulators]

hola, hace unos dias descargue el xcode 8.0, y tenia todos los simuladores a mi alcance hasta el iphone 7 plus, pero como donde estudio tienen una version mas antigua de xcode me vi obligado a descargar la version 7.3.1 de internet, por consiguiente conserve ambos xcode, pero al instalar y abrir el xcode mas viejo, me di cuenta que solo aparece el "generic ios device" lo mismo me paso cuando volvi a abrir el xcode 8.0 lo cual me parecio raro,  me gustaria volver a tener todos esos simuladores que antes tenia, intente abrir un nuevo proyecto en ambos xcode pero aun asi sigue el "generic ios device"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ve a Download Simulators y descargalos de nuevo no es necesario Desinstalar el otro Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Desinstala uno de los dos Xcode y te volverá todo a la normalidad. Hay problemas de convivencia entre ambos en esta ocasión...